# Executing closure on Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, closures, symfony-2.8

I'm trying to execute a closure that resides inside an array on a Twig template. Below you could find a simplified snippet of which I'm trying:

---

```
//Symfony controller
...
$funcs = array(
    "conditional" => function($obj){
        return $obj->getFoo() === $obj::TRUE_FOO
    }
);
$this->render('template_name', array('funcs' => $funcs));
```

---

```
{# Twig template #}
{# obj var is set #}
...
{% if funcs.conditional(obj)%}
<p>Got it</p>
{% endif %}
```

---

When Twig renders the template, throws an exception complaining about an Array to string conversion

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in "template_name.html.twig".
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
1 linked Exception: ContextErrorException »
```

I will appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a closure you can use the the call method of the closure

http://php.net/manual/en/closure.call.php

You will end up with something like this

```
{{ funcs.conditional.call(obj, obj) }}
```

Since the first parameter must be the object that 'this' will refer too I am passing the same object as the first parameter.

No twig extension and no extra PHP code to do ;)

Comment: on this case, we should be call {{ funcs.conditional.call(funcs.conditional, obj) }}. That right?!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly execute a closure inside your Twig template. However, if you need to call some PHP inside your template, you should use [create a Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) and include your logic inside.

Comment: Thanks! But this solution doesn't work for me since the logic is variable

Comment: What do you mean by "the logic is variable"?

Comment: It could be many different conditional functions, with different conditions. I consider that is not efficient to put as many twig extensions as different conditionals because it would kill performance on template rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Twig does not allow to do this directly. You can either add a simple function to Twig to handle the execution of closures or wrap your closure in a class to be able to use the attribute function of Twig (since directly calling `attribute(_context, 'myclosure', args)` will trigger a Fatal Error as Twig will return the closure directly and ignore the given arguments since `_context` is an array).

---

A simple Twig extension that achieves this purpose would look like this for Symfony 2.8+. (For Symfony 4, see the [new documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html))

```
// src/AppBundle/Twig/Extension/CoreExtensions.php
namespace AppBundle\Twig\Extension;

class CoreExtensions extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('execute', [$this, 'executeClosure'])
        ];
    }

    public function executeClosure(\Closure $closure, $arguments)
    {
        return $closure(...$arguments);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'core_extensions_twig_extension';
    }
}
```

Then, in your templates, you simply have to call execute:

```
{{ execute(closure, [argument1, argument2]) }}
```

---

Without extending Twig, one way to get around this problem is to use a class that acts as a wrapper for your closure and to use the [`attribute`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) function of Twig as it can be used to call a method of an object.

```
// src/AppBundle/Twig/ClosureWrapper.php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

/**
 * Wrapper to get around the issue of not being able to use closures in Twig
 * Since it is possible to call a method of a given object in Twig via "attribute",
 * the only purpose of this class is to store the closure and give a method to execute it
 */
class ClosureWrapper
{
    private $closure;

    public function __construct($closure)
    {
        $this->closure = $closure;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return ($this->closure)(...func_get_args());
    }
}
```

Then, you simply need to give a ClosureWrapper instance to your template when rendering instead of the closure itself:

```
use AppBundle\Twig\ClosureWrapper;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function myAction()
    {
        $localValue = 2;
        $closure = new ClosureWrapper(function($param1, $param2) use ($localValue) {
            return $localValue + $param1 + $param2;
        });

        return $this->render('mytemplate.html.twig', ['closure' => $closure]);
    }

    ...
```

Eventually, in your template, you need to use [`attribute`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) to execute the closure you defined in your controller:

```
// Displays 12
{{ attribute(closure, 'execute', [4, 6]) }}
```

However, this is a bit redundant as, [internally](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/2.x/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php), the [`attribute`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) function of Twig unpacks the given arguments as well. By using the above code, for each call, arguments are successively unpacked, packed and unpacked again.